# Python - refactor of try/except block - double call for super() method

Tags: python, refactoring, try-catch

At beggining, sorry for title of the question - I could not came up a better one. Suggestions are welcome.

I wrote `__init__` method for my class, which works great, but looks ugly. Can it be improved? I mean the duplicate line calling function `super()`.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Creates selenium driver.

    :param args: Non-keyword variables passed to selenium driver.
    :param kwargs: Keyword variables passed to selenium driver.
    """

    try:
        phantomjs_path = 'node_modules/.bin/phantomjs'
        super().__init__(phantomjs_path, *args, **kwargs)
    except WebDriverException:
        phantomjs_path = 'phantomjs'
        super().__init__(phantomjs_path, *args, **kwargs)
```

---

Update:

```
try:
    phantomjs_path = 'node_modules/.bin/phantomjs'
except WebDriverException:
    phantomjs_path = 'phantomjs'
finally:
    super().__init__(phantomjs_path, *args, **kwargs)
```

It does not work - it seems obvious.

Comment: Do you really need the phantomjs_path variable?

Comment: @GergelySipkai: No, I don't need it. I just want to call `super()` with success.

Comment: Then you should just call super().

Comment: @GergelySipkai: Double `super()` without define variables of course works. But they are still duplicate lines. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a loop to avoid writing the `super` line twice:

```
for phantomjs_path in ('node_modules/.bin/phantomjs', 'phantomjs'):
    try:
        super().__init__(phantomjs_path, *args, **kwargs)
        break
    except WebDriverException:
        pass
```

Otherwise, there is not much you can do here.  The only way to handle exceptions in Python is with the `try/except` construct, which will always take at least 4 lines.

Comment: As you say - probably there is no other way. I think that your solution would be better (despite longer code).